# Textbox lost focus not firing on dialog close from top

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox bind to a property in viewModel. I have made validation check in viewmodel and check whether user makes any changes to the data. So on exit it ask user to commit the changes to database.

Problem I am facing is when I change the value in textbox and user directly clicks on the close button dialog the lost focus doesn't occur and value are not changed in property. So I used

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

I do change the property but creates an entry in undo stack for each key press. I want to update the property only on lost focus i.e. one changeset even when user clicj the close button from top of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

maybe ask the user to save  if he has changes and he tries to close ?

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 

            this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(MainWindow_Closing);
        }

        void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            //ask the user to save , if needed to 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following to your app.xaml.cs. and then your UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus should work.

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Button), ButtonBase.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ButtonClick));
         //...
     }

    private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null && sender is Button)
        {
            (sender as Button).Focus();
        }
    }
```